# Strange characters in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

[image]After updating PyCharm to the latest version, an unexpected issue arose: the IDE's tabs started displaying strange characters instead of the usual English text.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

I contacted the support and help center of IDE provider. Based on their suggestions, I tried reinstalling and using jetBrain direct installation.

Comment: What is a "strange character"? Screenshot?

Comment: Picture added to the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Pycharm support and their solution helped:
I resolved it by deleting the following file:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2023.2\options\others.xml

Comment: Although this solution works, I still get this error whenever I restart Pycharm. It is really annoying. Every day I should delete that other.xml file!